# WebApi 2 Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a little confused with WebApi and MVC.
I created a blank WebApi project and selected Individual User Accounts as the authentication method.

This generated the **AccountController : ApiController** class. In here there are methods for Registering, Getting user info, etc, but there is no method for logging in.

How is the MVC user supposed to log in?

Cheers,
/r3plica

Comment: If you created ApiController why are you asking how MVC user logs in? i think you are mixing 2 things that you should not

Comment: I didn't create anything, I created a blank project and it created all the classes. But there is no method for logging in for either the web api or mvc

Comment: AccountController : ApiController <-- This is API

Comment: API authorization and authentication: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Yeah I get that Dmitry, I want to know why there is no way to log in. Am I supposed to write my own methods? Does MVC need a seperate way to login or can they both use the Api method (that I assume I will have to create)?

Comment: I know the difference between authorization and authentication. It is the authentication I am interseted in :)

Comment: All right, so the API might be called from browser or by CURL operations OR making simple http request from another server. which means you need to work on it. You can implement basic authentication: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication .Note: each request is separate, so you cant leave a cookie. I recommend you reading about OAuth2, which is used a lot by API's

Answer (score 0):

In default Web Api template is using OWIN middleware to authenticate user.

In Startup.Auth.cs you can find configuration info about urls for authentication.

```
 static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "self";

        UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token") - this url for get token for user,
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }
```

After you send request to TokenEndPointPath with user name and password in parameters, OWIN middleware call method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials which implemented in ApplicationOAuthProvider in default template with user account.In this method you can check user name and password and grant access to user.

You can find default implementation of this method below.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = _userManagerFactory())
        {
            IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
    }
```